# Converting DWG to DWF - Understanding externalid property

Tags: autodesk-forge

To send our model to Forge, we have converted(published) our DWG to DWFx file. We are doing that because DWFx files allow us to append additional properties for each element.

Is there some possibility to know the externalId property of Forge, during DWG/DWFx convertion? Maybe using the BeginEntity event of Publisher object(Autodesk.AutoCAD.Publishing Autocad.NET API)?
On this post http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2009/02/uniqueid-dwf-and-ifc-guid.html, Jeremy explains how translate episodeId guid + UniqueID of Revit element to DWF ID. But it was not feasible at Autocad. Do you have some clue about that?

I have done all steps that Jeremy have explained, but I did some changes in my code as change Revit UniqueId for CAD Handle, even so I could not get the externalId property.

Comment: With my test, the externalId of Forge is a Base64 string from an Guid. Such Guid is visible if checking the DWFx in Navisworks, but I do not either find how to get the Guid from the properties in AutoCAD. Please bear with me checking with engineer team

Comment: I asked around, but have not got a comment where / how the guid is generated. I expanded the audience. Once there is any feedback, I will get back to you.

Comment: our engineer team gave it a test with my steps, but it is interesting, the external id  with their DWF is just entity handle of AutoCAD. We are discussing again why we have the different test results.

Answer (score 0):

it has been a long time without update. my apology for the delay! just fyi what might be useful about the externalId of DWFx.  It can be got by the steps below:

1. Copy the *.dwfx file to another file with extension ".zip",
2. Extract the ZIP file.
3. View the XML file: `dwf\documents\B32F5310-75D4-4AC6-98DA-F27855056814\1830A475-854B-4F12-A992-7339E636067D.content.xml`

[image]

you will find such id with the object name + AutoCAD entity handle, which means when AutoCAD exports file to DWFx, it generates such id for DWFx

[image]